# LocalStorage or SQLite ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, sqlite

I'm working on my app that let me to store my online DVD's information on my iphone. Just wonder to use localStorage or SQLite. Also I'm gonna update my app in the future and I dont want to loose my stored data. Which one do you suggest me ?!

Cheers

Comment: what may be the data size...? list counts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know much about localStograge anyway SQLite will give you good options:

1. Portable to Android
2. Can be updated without losing your previous database.

here is a sample code to init DB and upgrade it.

```
+(void) InitalizeDB
{
    NSFileManager   *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError         *error;
    NSString        *dbPath = [self getDBPath];
    BOOL            success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];

    if(!success) 
    {       
        NSString    *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"QuestionsDB.sqlite"];

        success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];
        if (!success)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    if (success)
    {
        if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &gDatabase) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            sqlite3_close(gDatabase);
            gDatabase = nil;
        }
    }
    if (gDatabase != nil)
        [self Upgrade];
}

+(void)Upgrade
{
    sqlite3         *NewDatabase = nil;
    NSString        *NewDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"QuestionsDB.sqlite"];
    const char      *szVersion = "SELECT DBVersion FROM Version";
    sqlite3_stmt    *sqlOldVersion;
    sqlite3_stmt    *sqlNewVersion;

    if (sqlite3_open([NewDBPath UTF8String], &NewDatabase) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_close(NewDatabase);
        NewDatabase = nil;
    }

    if (NewDatabase != nil)
    {
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(gDatabase, szVersion, -1, &sqlOldVersion, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to compile sql statment %s", sqlite3_errmsg(gDatabase));
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(NewDatabase, szVersion, -1, &sqlNewVersion, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to compile sql statment %s", sqlite3_errmsg(NewDatabase));
        if (sqlite3_step(sqlOldVersion) == SQLITE_ROW && sqlite3_step(sqlNewVersion) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            if (sqlite3_column_int(sqlOldVersion, 0) < sqlite3_column_int(sqlNewVersion, 0))
            {
                [self UpgradeCategories:NewDatabase];
                [self UpgradeQuestions:NewDatabase];
                [self UpgradeQuestionChoices:NewDatabase];
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            NSAssert(0, @"Failed to retreive questions database version.");
        }


    }   
    sqlite3_close(NewDatabase);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud, So if I update the app is it gonna stop replacing  the SQLite file on the pervious one automatically or do I need some kind of code for that ?

Comment: No, you copy the SQLite file to the document director if not exist. So the SQLite file that is in the bundle directoy is read-only and the one you will copy to the Documents directory is read/write.

when you update your application lets say V2 will check if the file exist with older version it will update the records using a bunch of SQL statement.

I will edit the post now to show you a sample of it.

Comment: Thanks mate , I have another problem , that I want to insert a data after pressing a button to my DB. im using this : MyDvDsList *dbCrud = [[MyDvDsList alloc] init];
    NSMutableString *fldTxt = [NSMutableString stringWithString:passTitle];
    [dbCrud InsertRecords: "have no idea what i should do here !!"]; and also MyDvDsList is the my SQLite class that i have my insertRecords there :/

Comment: please edit the question so I can see the code formated. or study an SQLite tutorial as it seems you need to use SQLite wrapper to help you get your project done quickly
https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

Answer (score 2):

> my online DVD's information

can be large information, then use core data or SQLite.

> Also I'm gonna update my app in the future and I dont want to loose my
>   stored data

if you update without deleting the old version, SQLite data remains. This works same for NSUserDefault too. You can use Keychains for permanant data storage, but for small amount of data. Can't say more without knowing more about your requirement.